# Sqlite multiple number ranges

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an sqlite table that looks like this:

| time | number |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-02-23 03:00:00 | -0.0415385690329766 |
| 2024-02-23 03:15:00 | -1.24717775905644 |
| 2024-02-23 03:30:00 | -0.598224308602898 |
| 2024-02-24 03:00:00 | -0.391209672798098 |
| 2024-02-24 03:15:00 | -3.01903966597076 |
| 2024-02-24 03:30:00 | -1.05561725758225 |
| 2024-02-25 03:00:00 | 0.134035229803659 |
| 2024-02-25 03:15:00 | -2.0615858352579757 |
| 2024-02-25 03:30:00 | 0.0470381575095116 |
| 2024-02-25 03:45:00 | 0.072381723812783 |

Is it possible to count the numbers based on the first decimal place?
I would like to see how many numbers are between multiple decimal places (for example: between -0.1 and -0.2 and so on)

edit:
for example:
0.18, 0.139, 0.12 should belong to '0.1:0.2' group.
other numbers like:
1.13, 1.173, 1.132 should belong to '1.1:1.2' group.

The result should look something like this:

| range | count |
| --- | --- |
| -3.1:-3.0 | 1 |
| -2.1:-2.0 | 1 |
| -1.3-1.2 | 1 |
| -1.2-1.1 | 0 |
| -1.1-1.0 | 1 |
| -1:-0.9 | 0 |
| -0.9:-0.8 | 0 |
| -0.8:-0.7 | 0 |
| -0.7:-0.6 | 0 |
| -0.6:-0.5 | 1 |
| -0.5:-0.4 | 0 |
| -0.4:-0.3 | 1 |
| -0.3:-0.2 | 0 |
| -0.2:-0.1 | 0 |
| -0.1:0 | 1 |
| 0:0.1 | 2 |
| 0.1:0.2 | 1 |
| 0.2:0.3 | 0 |
| 0.3:0.4 | 0 |
| 0.4:0.5 | 0 |
| 0.5:0.6 | 0 |
| 0.6:0.7 | 0 |
| 0.7:0.8 | 0 |
| 0.8:0.9 | 0 |
| 0.9:1.0 | 0 |

I found this solution but it's not working:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22491/how-do-i-calculate-count-for-a-range-without-needing-to-use-multiple-queries

```
SELECT
  case
    when number BETWEEN 0 AND -0.1 THEN '0:-0.1'
    when number BETWEEN -0.1 AND -0.2 THEN '-0.1:-0.2'
    when number BETWEEN -0.2 AND -0.3 THEN '-0.2:-0.3'
    when number BETWEEN -0.4 AND -0.5 THEN '-0.4:-0.5'
    when number BETWEEN -1 AND -2 THEN '-1:-2'
    else 'other numbers'
  end as `range`,
  COUNT(1) as count
from table1
group by `range`
```

Now I have this as a result so something really wrong with my query but I can't figure it out.

| range | count |
| --- | --- |
| other numbers | 10 |

db fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/S0I1MBaT

Comment: Hint: SQLite has the `FLOOR()` function...

Comment: Your question says you want to `GROUP BY` numbers using _only_ their 1st decimal digit - but your posted _expected results_ show you grouping by their most-significant digits instead. Please clarify your post.

Comment: Does your build of SQLite [have `-DSQLITE_ENABLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS` enabled](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html)? If not (and if you can't make your own SQLite build) then you might be SOL...

Comment: Hello Dai! Thank you for taking time to read my post.  My english knowledge is limited and excuse me for my sql ignorance. Now I can't figure out how could I clarify this more. If there is a number between 0 and -0.1 (eg: -0.03, -0.09) it should count and belong to its group '0:-0.1', and eg: -0.21 and -0.28 should belong to '-0.2:-0.3' and so on.

Comment: I'm asking if `0.1` and `1.1` and `2.1` be grouped together or not, as they all share the same 1st decimal digit (`0.1`) value.

Comment: They should not be grouped together. eg: 0.1 and 0.12 and 0.135 should be counted to its own group: '0.1:0.2'. The other numbers eg: 1.12, 1.16, 1.173 belongs to the group '1.1:1.2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They should not be grouped together. eg: 0.1 and 0.12 and 0.135 should be counted to its own group: '0.1:0.2'. The other numbers eg: 1.12, 1.16, 1.173 belongs to the group '1.1:1.2'

All you need to do is *round-off* the numbers to 1-decimal-place.

Unfortunately, SQLite doesn't have a `round()` function that accepts a `digits` parameter, but you can work-around it by using `floor()` with a 10x premultiplication (and then dividing by 10 again afterwards).

- For example, if `t.number == 0.234`

  - ...then `FLOOR( t.number ) == 0` - which we don't want

    - ...but `FLOOR( t.number * 10 ) == 2` - which is better

      - ...so `FLOOR( t.number * 10 ) / 10 == 0.2` - which is perfect

Like so:

```
WITH c AS (

    SELECT
        FLOOR( t.number * 10 ) / 10 AS roundedNumber,
        t.number,
        t.time
    FROM
        myTable AS t
)
SELECT
    c.roundedNumber,
    COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM
    c
GROUP BY
    c.roundedNumber
ORDER BY
    c.roundedNumber;
```

Because SQL's `GROUP BY` step is conceptually performed *before* the `SELECT` part, you'll need to use an inner-query or a CTE (my answer uses a CTE).

---

If you want to use a *histogram-bin-style* column name for the grouping key, then do this:

```
WITH c AS (

    SELECT
        FLOOR( t.number * 10 ) / 10 AS roundedNumber,
        t.number,
        t.time
    FROM
        myTable AS t
)
SELECT
    ( CAST( c.roundedNumber AS text ) || '-' || CAST( c.roundedNumber + 0.1 AS text ) ) AS "Range",
    c.roundedNumber,
    COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM
    c
GROUP BY
    c.roundedNumber
ORDER BY
    c.roundedNumber;
```

...should give you results like this:

| Range | roundedNumber | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "0.1-0.2" | 0.1 | 123 |
| "0.4-0.5" | 0.4 | 9 |
| "1.2-1.3" | 1.2 | 1 |

Note that there will be gaps in the output data - but you can fill those in by doing an `INNER JOIN` on [a `GENERATE_SERIES()` table expression](https://www.sqlite.org/series.html).

Comment: Thank you Dai! That is a very satisfactory answer. I really appreciate it! Now I have to study it. I'm using sqlite3 (3.42.0) module with python so I think I don't have math functions. I have to figure it out how can I make it work for me. Thank you! You are very kind!

Comment: @scidar I'd be surprised if you didn't have math functions in your SQLite database, honestly. I think DBFiddle's build is an exception. Try running a simple query like `SELECT TRUNC(  123.45 ) AS n` and if you get `123` as the result then you're fine.

Comment: You are right, I have it.  :) Thank you for your care and detailed answers. You are great. You helped me a lot!

Comment: There is a comma in the code after "t.time" in both of the codes so it drops "syntax error". But it is working as intended if I remove it.

Comment: @scidar Thank you for catching that. I've corrected my answer.